# Covariance of Two Quadratic Forms

Tags: probability, expected-value, covariance, quadratic-form

We're looking for the $\operatorname{Cov}\left[x^T A x, ~x^T B x\right]$ where $x$ is random variable and mean-centered, but not independent and $A$ and $B$ are symmetric matrices. The fundamental term to compute is $E\left[x^T A x x^T B x\right]$, a quartic form. For the normal case, you can find this in the matrix cookbook. Has anyone figured this out in general?

Comment: Not a whole lot of simplification is available for the general case you pose.  But if you intend that the $x_i$ be iid, for instance, or exchangeable, or uncorrelated, then extensive simplification is possible.  Could you clarify for us what assumptions you are making about the first four moments of $x$ (beyond "mean-centered," which implies all means are zero)?  BTW, I'm curious about what you mean by "heterogeneous," because this expectation looks like a *homogeneous* quartic form in the components of $A$ and $B$ to me.

Comment: Maybe you don't need this anymore. I think you may find this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0jBgMDkfUg.

Answer (score 1):

In the special case when $A$ and $B$ commute, they are simultaneously diagonalisable. If the spectrum of $A$ is made of the $\lambda_i$'s and the spectrum of $B$ of the $\xi_i$'s, then
$$\text{Cov}[x^T A x, ~x^T B x]=\sum_i \lambda_i\xi \text{var}(X_i^2)$$
if $X_i$ is the $i$-th coordinate of $X$ in the orthonormal basis.

Comment: You must be assuming both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric (which is reasonable, but ought to be made explicit).

Comment: I think you must also be assuming normality (and independence), otherwise you can't ignore the off-diagonal terms.