# covariance of squared projections

Tags: expected-value, covariance, quadratic-form

Given a vector $x$ of independent mean-zero random variables, and two nonrandom orthogonal unit vectors $u,v$, does $u'v=0$ imply $cov(x'uu'x,x'vv'x)=0$? If so, what is the proof? If not, what happens to the off-diagonal terms in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/381817/138422) answer?

Comment: Don't you also want to assume the components of $x$ are independent of each other?  If not, counterexamples are easy to construct (e.g., take $u=(1,0)^\prime$ and $v=(0,1)^\prime$).

Comment: @whuber yup, thanks

Comment: @whuber Oh I see your point,  in the question to the answer I cited $x$ is not assumed independent. So a counter-example to the answer there is $A=B=I$ in $R^2$, where the answer is off by $2 cov(x_1^2,x_2^2)$ which can be nonzero. Still, I am interested in the independent case.

Comment: Your covariance is a fourth moment of the distribution of $x.$  Look for counterexamples among leptokurtic or platykurtic distributions.  For instance, let the components of $x$ have independent Uniform$(-1,1)$ distributions and pick $u=(1,1),$ $v=(1,-1).$ The covariance equals $-4/15\ne 0.$